# OpenCV and Visual Studio configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration, opencv

In *Learning OpenCV*, it mentions the following regarding configuring OpenCV and Visual Studio:

> In Visual Studio, it is necessary to
>   create a project and to configure the
>   setup so that  (a) the libraries
>   highgui.lib, cxcore.lib, ml.lib, and
>   cv.lib are linked and (b) the
>   preprocessor will search the OpenCV …
>   /opencv/*/include directories for
>   header files. These  “include”
>   directories will typically be named
>   something like C:/program
>   files/opencv/cv/include,
>   …/opencv/cxcore/include, …
>   /opencv/ml/include, and …
>   /opencv/otherlibs/ highgui.

How would I go about creating and configuring the project this way?

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to set environment variables first. You just need to add the location of the bin class to the directory path.(just add a semicolon and paste the path ). Then after creating a visual c++ console project you have to include needed include directories path to specific location.(If you need more explanation on that just add a comment)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the environment variables, and then set the projects properties (C++ and Linker) according to your OpenCV version and directories. See my step-bystep guide with instructions and a video:

http://devel-open.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/opencv-visual-studio-2008.html